# How to select unique pairs in SQL Server according to the third parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the test table with three columns `Fir`, `Sec` and `Val`.

```
Fir    Sec     Val
------------------
A       A       1
A       B       7
A       C       31
B       A       3
B       D       4
B       F       7
C       X       10
C       Y       10
C       Z       9
```

I am trying to extract all the unique values of `Fir` with a minimum alphabetical value of `Sec` which corresponds to the maximum value of `Val`.

For a given text table, the output must be

```
Fir    Sec
----------
A       C    
B       F    
C       X
```

I manage this somehow with the script below, but I think there should be an simpler solution to produce the same result.

```sql
SELECT 
    Fir, MIN(Sec) AS Sec
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.Fir, b.Sec, MaxVal
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              Fir, MAX(Val) AS MaxVal
          FROM 
              Test3
          GROUP BY 
              Fir) a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Test3 b ON a.Fir = b.Fir AND a.MaxVal = b.Val) c
GROUP BY 
    Fir
ORDER BY 
    Fir
```

Any suggestion to improve this would be appreciated.

Code to generate sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test3
(
    Fir CHAR(5),
    Sec CHAR(5),
    Val INT
)

INSERT INTO Test3 
VALUES ('A', 'A', 1), ('A', 'B', 7), ('A', 'C', 31),
       ('B', 'A', 3), ('B', 'D', 4), ('B', 'F', 7),
       ('C', 'X', 10), ('C', 'Y', 10), ('C', 'Z', 9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bite; this method uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to do the heavy-lifting:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        Fir,
        Sec,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fir ORDER BY Val DESC, Sec ASC) AS order_id
    FROM
        Test3)
SELECT
    Fir,
    Sec
FROM
    x
WHERE
    order_id = 1;
```

Comment: Yes it works better with that edit, and it could probably do with an `ORDER BY` at the end as well. But it's worth nothing that it already got the "right" result without the change, although I'll agree it was non-deterministic :)

Answer (score 1):

You achieve the same by using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT M.FIR,MIN(SEC) FROM TEST3 M
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  FIR,MAX(VAL) SECC FROM TEST3 GROUP BY FIR) S ON S.SECC=M.VAL AND S.FIR=M.FIR
GROUP BY M.FIR
```